# How to gather user information like name and mobile number before Chatbot starts conversation in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I need to gather the name and mob number of the user before he starts interacting with the Chatbot. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

- You will need to create 2 parameters - name and phoneNumber to capture name and phone numbers.
- Using the @sys.phone-number you can capture phone numbers from the user.
  [image]
- Using the @sys.given-name or @sys.last-name you can capture user's name.
  [image]

**Please note**: currently only US English names are supported by the system entities in Dialogflow. So there may be some cases where you may not be able to capture all the names.

Answer (score 0):

> gather user information like name and mobile number before Chatbot

In your case, you need to use  [events](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events)

Step 1. trigger an event when your app initialize like from nodejs server and angular

[image]

> Events are another way to trigger the intent without user interaction 
>   when you intent trigger you can ask information

[image]